# Order of prime ideals over split primes in the class group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, proof-verification, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $\mathcal O_K$ ($K$ a quadratic field) and let $P$ have norm $p$ where $p$ is a split prime. Is it possible for the ideal class $[P]$ to have order less than three? I feel like this must happen sometimes, as e.g. $3$ splits in $\mathcal O_K$ where $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5}),$ but the class group $Cl(K)$ is $C_2$. So if $P_3$ is a prime ideal of norm $3$ here, it's class must have order 1 or 2. However, at the same time, $P_3 \overline{P_3}=(3)$ is principal, and so $[\overline{P_3}]=[P_3]^{-1}$. But $P_3 \neq \overline{ P_3}$. So must we have $[\overline{P_3}]=[P_3]$, in this case, since the order of the class divides 2? Is there any other way of telling when $[\overline{P}]=[P]$ in general?

In a similar vein, can ideal classes of prime ideals over ramified primes $p$ ever be of order 1 or are they always order 2? We would need $(a+b\sqrt d)=P \implies a^2-db^2=p$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb Z$ (or $\frac{1}{2}\mathbb Z$, if $d \equiv 1 \pmod 4$) and $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$. Are there simple examples when this happens? **Attempt 1:** since $p$ ramifies, either $p|d$ or $p=2, d \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. In the first case, we get $a^2=p-db^2$ which is divisible by $p$. Hence $p|a$ and so $d>0$. In the second case, $a^2-3b^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \implies a^2+b^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \implies 2 \nmid a,b$.

**Attempt 2:** For ramified primes, $P=\overline P$ and so $a+b\sqrt d \sim a-b\sqrt d $. If $d<-1, d \equiv 2,3 \pmod 4$ then the units are the elements of norm 1, so $\pm 1$. So either $a+b\sqrt d=a-b\sqrt d $ or $-a+b\sqrt d$. So either $b=0$ or $a=0$, but then $p=a^2$ or $-db^2$, which gives a contradiction unless $b=1,p=-d$. (is this argument correct?)

Comment: W.r.t your second question the answer is yes they can be of order 1, any ring with a trivial class group has this property. Specifically $\Bbb{C}[I]$, which is a Euclidean domain and hence a PID and hence has trivial class group, but has $(2)=(1+i)^2$.

Comment: @jgon I'm only talking about $\mathcal O_K$ where $K$ is a quadratic field. I'm not sure what $\mathbb C[I]$ is.

Comment: Sorry $\Bbb{Q}[i]$ sorry the app doesn't let you preview latex in comments so I didn't catch the typo. The ring of integers is $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, and in this ring $(2)=(1+i)^2$. I.e. 2 ramifies, but $(1+i)$ is principal, so $[(1+i)]$ has order 1.

Comment: @jgon Ahh ok, So we're talking about the Gaussian integers. That's interesting then, as $1+i \sim 1- i$ since $-i$ is a unit. I think this is the only time this happens, so is this the only example there is?

Comment: @James: Why do you think that $a + b \sqrt{d} \sim a - b \sqrt{d}$ implies that $b = 0$? What is the unique (ramified) prime lying above $3$ in $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, for example?

Comment: I was accidentally thinking only of imaginary quadratic fields. If $d<-1,$ then the units are the elements of norm 1, so $\pm 1$. So either $a+b\sqrt d=a-b\sqrt d $ or $a+b\sqrt d=-a+b\sqrt d$. So actually, either $a=0$ or $b=0$. I'll edit my attempt.

Comment: @James: You also have extra units if $d = -3$. But my point was to get you to see that the possibility that $a = 0$ exists. My example above is not unique to real quadratic fields; it works just as well with looking at $5$ in $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$.

Comment: @BrandonCarter Thanks. It took me a while to edit my attempt to one that I think is now correct, using your comment. I think I understand the issue a lot more now, at least.